# Access commonly used data from outside of project

Tags: c++

I'm investigating the best way to store and access commonly used data, which can then be used in different projects. Rather than declare and define the same data in each project, I'd like to store the data in a single place. This should make it easy if I need to update the data or add new data.

I've tried two methods without much luck.

---

Method #1 (Header file with matching .cpp file)

data_library.h

```
#ifndef DATA_LIBRARY_H
#define DATA_LIBRARY_H

extern double motor_torque;

#endif
```

data_library.cpp

```
#include "data_library.h"

double motor_torque = 3.6;
```

new_project.cpp

```
#include "data_library.h"

int main() {
std::cout << "\nMotor torque is " << motor_torque << "Nm";
}
```

In Visual Studio this gives an error "LNK2001: Unresolved external symbol".

---

Method #2 (External .txt file)

I'm comfortable reading from external .txt files, but I'm concerned that should the file move location this will break the program. I'd prefer to have all data stored within the project / solution.

---

Is there a standard method for this that is "good practice"?

Comment: The error is probably because you don't build with the `data_library.cpp` source file.

Comment: Method three just make them `const static` in a header?

Comment: Method four: if the values wont change at runtime. `#define MOTOR_TORQUE 3.8`

Comment: Depends on what sort of data it is. If you're loading data that can change, the 'proper' solution would be a database, probably (you can do small amounts in shared files - but you have to worry about sharing.) If you're defining types - if it's all in one language, a shared header file is a way. If it's between different languages, defining a meta-file, which can be processed into the relevant types for each language at compile time is a consistent way.

Comment: As you can see there's really no single one "true" way or best practice for this. It all depends on your use-cases, what the data is used for, and how many applications will use this "shared" data.

Comment: Also about storing in files, don't forget that a large majority of programs store run-time configuration data in files. While it is true that it's a problem if some user randomly moves your file, it's a user problem and not a program problem. If the user moves your data files, then he or she only has him/her self to blame.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks, that helped. I needed to change to "not using precompiled headers" too on the data_library.cpp file.

Comment: @Tezirg Please don't. Macros as constants is plain dumb.

Comment: @PasserBy I think thats your opinion, unless you can give valid arguments. Now, for embedded systems it is actually very common to use constant macros to store the GPIO pin numbers / Register values / Masks and so on.

Comment: @H.Wilkinson at what point do the data change ? only at 'compile time' or can it change due to some user action ala. configuration ? You need to answer what sort of data this is ?

Comment: @darune The data may change from estimated values to tested values. For example, torque may be designed to be 3.6Nm but after testing is actually 3.8Nm.

Comment: @Tezirg There is a thing called `constexpr`. There are literally no downsides to using them instead of macros. Macros pollutes your namespace. Macros are less flexible. Macros have less tooling support. Macros aren't variables. Something being common doesn't make it less dumb, the list isn't exhaustive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your code code. It compiles well for me.
I use gcc-4.8 and: `g++ -g -Wall -o new_project new_project.cpp data_library.cpp`

data_library.h

```
#ifndef DATA_LIBRARY_H
#define DATA_LIBRARY_H

extern double motor_torque;

#endif //DATA_LIBRARY_H
```

data_library.cpp

```
#include "data_library.h"

double motor_torque = 3.6;
```

new_project.cpp

```
#include "data_library.h"

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "\nMotor torque is " << motor_torque << " Nm" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Don't forget to `return` in the main function.

And about the second question, you can make a specific namespace that contains all your data such as:

database.h

```
namespace Database {
    constexpr double motor_torque = 3.6;
    // other data goes here
}
```

Usage: `#include "database.h"` then `std::cout << Database::motor_torque << std::endl;`

Comment: "Don't forget to return in the main function." you cannot forget to return in `main` because its the only place where there is an implicit `return`

Comment: The namespace Database method I've got working. I'm having trouble using the same method for a struct. For example:

    `struct motor{
       int torque;
    } motor_01;
    motor_01.torque = 4;`

Comment: @H.Wilkinson to use the value to initialize a strct member you would write `struct motor { int torque = Database::motor_torque; };`